# How Web API returns multiple types

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am just wondering whether it is possible to return multiple types in a single  Web Api. For example, I want an api to return both lists of customers and orders (these two sets of data may or may not relate to each other?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

To return multiple types, you can wrap them into anonymous type, there are two possible approaches:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    var listInt = new List<int>() { 1, 2 };
    var listString = new List<string>() { "a", "b" };

    return ControllerContext.Request
        .CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { listInt, listString });
}
```

Or:

```
public object Get()
{
    var listInt = new List<int>() { 1, 2 };
    var listString = new List<string>() { "a", "b" };

    return  new { listInt, listString };
}
```

Also remember that *The XML serializer does not support anonymous types*. So, you have to ensure that request should have header:

```
Accept: application/json
```

in order to accept json format

Comment: Note: The request accept needs to be application/json, as the xml serializer will respond will an error, unsure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use JsonNetFormatter serializer, because the default serializer- DataContractJsonSerializer can not serialize anonymous types.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    List<Customer> cust = GetCustomers();
    List<Products> prod= GetCustomers();
    //create an anonymous type with 2 properties
    var returnObject = new { customers = cust, Products= prod };
    return new HttpResponseMessage<object>(returnObject , new[] { new JsonNetFormatter() });
}
```

You could get JsonNetFormatter  from [HERE](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Using-JSONNET-with-ASPNET-b2423706#content)

Comment: im getting an error on the HttpResponseMessage (and also the JsonNetFormatter but i think i know why they are there) saying "The non-generic type 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage' cannot be used with type arguments". Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
return ControllerContext.Request
       .CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { listInt, listString });
```

use this:

```
return Ok(new {new List<int>() { 1, 2 }, new List<string>() { "a", "b" }});
```

Comment: You could also do it this way:     return Ok( new { listInt, listString });

Comment: use ActionResult as the return type on the action method in the controller class.