# I want to return a table and the number of rows present in the table as a response

Tags: c#, webapi, actionmethod, httpresponsemessage

I have to send the noOfRecords variable in the response.

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetWareHouses(int pageNumber, int noofRows) 
{ 
var result = myModelObject.SelectTableData(pageNumber, noofRows); 
int numberOfRec = result.Count; /*I need to send this data in response.*/ 
if(numberOfRec>0) 
return  Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result) 
}
```

Comment: Did you check this post?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733205/how-web-api-returns-multiple-types

Answer (score 0):

In your function, there are at least two problems.

1. All paths needs to return a value. In your function, It is not.
2. If you are using Controllers to return value, I advice you to use  `IActionResult`

thus

```
public IActionResult GetWareHouses(int pageNumber, int noofRows) 
{ 
    var result = myModelObject.SelectTableData(pageNumber, noofRows); 
    int numberOfRec = result.Count; 

    if(numberOfRec>0) 
        return Ok(result) ;

    return BadRequest("problem");
}
```

Comment: `IActionResult` is from ASP.NET Core, yet the OP seems to be using ASP.NET Web API (from the `Request.CreateResponse` usage)